# how to make a full size blow-up of a small picture cutout in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What is the most efficient way to make a full size file out of a small cutout in Photoshop? For example, I have a picture of a group of people and I want to cut out just the face of one of them, but still want to post it on my flickr page as a file with usual resolution, 3000 x 2000 px, not just 30 x 30. I don't mind the obvious loss of quality, blurriness etc. It would be nice to be able to recompose after I cut my frame, so I don't want to delete the rest of my initial file but have it available during postprocessing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1, in your full size photo, IF the top layer is not the final effect, you have to make a stamp visible layer by: CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+N, CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+E

2, now use rectangal marquee tool to get that face of somebody. Then CTRL+C to copy.

3, CTRL+N to create a new document, the width and height of this document will automatically be the size of that face, which is very small. You need to do nothing but press OK.

4, CTRL+V to paste.

5, CTRL+ALT+I to change image size, change width to let's say 3000px, and height will be automatically changed according to aspect ratio.

That's it.